# Don't wait for POST request response Python Flask

Tags: python, post, flask, request

In Flask based Python app, I am trying to remotely run bash script with infinite loop which check if specific process exists - if so do nothing, else run this process. The problem is, app waits for POST response, which it will never be.
I have tried to run this process using os.system and subprocess.
In my app Python should only execute command without waiting for response (or end of script):

```
os.system("ssh pizerow '/home/pi/script.sh'")
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: A WGSI application (like Flask is designed to be) is not a good a place to do long running task since it is always bound to the request response cycle. It might be better "outsource" the task of checking the process to something like the systems startup service or [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If the process runs in the foreground, your app will wait for the process to be done. You may want to try running it in the background.
Try this:

```
os.system("nohup ssh pizerow '/home/pi/script.sh' >/dev/null 2>&1 &")
```

If you want the output to be logged, change it to:

```
os.system("nohup ssh pizerow '/home/pi/script.sh' >file.log 2>&1 &")
```